# How to track an event jquery chosen at vanila javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, addeventlistener, jquery-chosen

I'm using jquery chosen plugin for styling select dom element in my form. And i realize many line of code for my filter in vanila javascript without jquery. But the javascript fails to track the event which is hung on the form when the user selects the data stylized through the plugin in the select. How i can track this event in vanila js?

JS track event

```
let filterFormArray = document.querySelectorAll('[data-filter*=filter]');
filterFormArray.forEach(function(elem) {
    elem.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
        filterAjax(filterSerialize(this), e);
    });
});
```

JQ initialization chosen

```
$(".filter-box select").chosen({
    disable_search_threshold: 100, 
    allow_single_deselect: true, 
    max_selected_options: 5
});
```

Comment: Is your `JS track event` executes after `JQ initialization`?

Comment: @AswinKumar yes, i try after and before and nothing it all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I did it like this.

```
let getChosen = document.querySelectorAll('.chosen-results');
if (getChosen.length > 0) {
    getChosen.forEach(function(elem) {
        elem.addEventListener('click', function() {
            filterAjax(filterSerialize(this.closest('form')));
        });
    });
}
```